# How can I install phpmyadmin using the distribution archive(zip or tar) in apache2 server in ubuntu?

Tags: phpmyadmin, apache2

Using Debian packages is the easiest way to install phpmyadmin in apache2 server.But is there any helpful resources to install phpmyadmin using tar or zip archive in ubuntu.So far I have download zip archive of phpmyadmin and copied the content to the /var/www directory.Is there any resource which I get a help?

Comment: I had able to install it from a archive.For any other user help this resources will be helpful.
http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Setup

Answer (score 0):

Always read the documentation: http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Quick_Install